# Spring aop : Methods not intercepted

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-aop

I'm following this tutorial http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-aop-examples-advice/

This must be simple but I can't make it work in my app.
In my ApplicationContextConfig class, I add this to read the Spring-Customer.xml file;

`@ImportResource("classpath:/Spring-Customer.xml")`

My Spring-Customer.xml is exactly the same as the tutorial.
In my controller, I had this

```
@RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView list(){
        List<PersonDto> personDtos = personService.getAllPersons();
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("index");
        model.addObject("persons",personDtos);
        model.addObject("roles",personService.getRoles());


        System.out.println("*************************");
        customerService.printName();
        System.out.println("*************************");
        customerService.printURL();
        System.out.println("*************************");
        try {
            customerService.printThrowException();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return model;
    }
```

So everytime I run the app with localhost:8080 url, those sysout I inserted must see in the console.

Expected output should be

```
*************************
HijackBeforeMethod : Before method hijacked!
Customer name : Yong Mook Kim
*************************
HijackBeforeMethod : Before method hijacked!
Customer website : http://www.mkyong.com
*************************
HijackBeforeMethod : Before method hijacked!
```

what I see in the console is only this

```
*************************
Customer name : Yong Mook Kim
*************************
Customer website : http://www.mkyong.com
*************************
```

What am I doing wrong? Any advice would be helpful. Im new to spring aop. Thanks in advance.

EDIT : Spring-Customer.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="customerService" class="com.training.hibernate.services.impl.CustomerService">
        <property name="name" value="Yong Mook Kim" />
        <property name="url" value="http://www.mkyong.com" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="hijackBeforeMethodBean" class="com.training.hibernate.aspect.HijackBeforeMethod" />

    <bean id="customerServiceProxy"
                 class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">

        <property name="target" ref="customerService" />

        <property name="interceptorNames">
            <list>
                <value>hijackBeforeMethodBean</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Have you included the cglib library?

Comment: What version of spring are you using, can you also post your XML too, just so we can check...

Comment: Yes I included cglib. Im using spring 4.0.3.RELEASE

Comment: i dont see you adding the crosscut the way i have done it in the past, the problem is that with the new spring-boot and in class config it may have changed